# How to calculate this conditional probability?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I was given a conditional probability task with the following wording:

> The probability of having black hair is 60%. The probability of having blue eyes if your hair is not black is 40%. The probability of having blue eyes given that your hair is black is 10%. What is the probability of having black hair if your eyes are blue?

I am not a native speaker so I was conflicted if the task implies conditional probability or joint probability. Anyway I formulated the task as follows:

```
P(BH) = .6
P(BE | not BH) = .4
P(BE | BH) = 0.1 
P(BH | BE) = ?
```

**1. Is this correct? Did I understand the wording correctly?**

After formulating these equations I could derive the following:

```
P(BH) = .6
P(not BH) = .4
==================
P(BE | not BH) = .4
P(BE and not BH) / P(not BH) = .4
P(BE and not BH) / .4 = .4
P(BE and not BH) = 0.16
==================
P(BE | BH) = 0.1 
P(BE and BH) / P(BH) = 0.1
P(BE and BH) / 0.6 = 0.1
P(BE and BH) = 0.06
==================
P(BH | BE) = P(BH and BE) / P(BE)
```

**2. Now I am stuck as I don't know how I could get the `P(BE)` value. How to get value of `P(BE)`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is most readily answered by the use of Bayes theorem. From Bayes we have
$$
\mathbb P(BH\mid BE) = \frac{\mathbb P(BE\mid BH)\mathbb P(BH)}{\mathbb P(BE)}.
$$
We are given all of these quantities aside from $\mathbb P(BE)$, but we can compute $\mathbb P(BE)$ using the law of total probability and definition of conditional probability:
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(BE) &= \mathbb P(BE\cap BH)+\mathbb P(BE\cap BH^c)\\
&=\mathbb P(BE\mid BH)\mathbb P(BH) + \mathbb P(BE\mid BH^c)\mathbb P(BH^c)\\
&= \frac1{10} \cdot\frac35 + \frac25\cdot \frac25\\
&= \frac{11}{50}
\end{align}
It follows that
$$
\mathbb P(BH\mid BE) = \frac1{10}\cdot \frac35 \cdot\frac{50}{11} = \frac3{11}.
$$

Comment: @DanielMathias Thanks, I have corrected this in my post.